# Management of asynchronous commands

Tags: activerobot

I am working on a robotics project with C++ (drawing signs on board), on CRS CataLyst5 arm.

I have faced a problem:

I have many methods move in different directions, goToLocalizations, etc, but the problem is that when I run many of them in main without Sleep() function between each function they does not run properly. I think that the first one needs time (the time of robot movement) but when I put Sleep(10000) between them (I guessed that 10 seconds are enough for the movement) all is ok. This is very ineffective and slow solution. Would you like to give me some solutions to avoid the use of Sleep ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that you are using a [CRS Catalyst 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRS_Robotics) arm, I assume that you are using the [CRS ActiveRobot](http://www.thermoscientific.fr/com/cda/product/detail/0,1055,21981,00.html) ActiveX control.

A quick look through [this ActiveRobot Tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44659351/Tutorial-Active-Robot) suggests that [all robot commands are asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation), so when you command the gripper to open (using `Robot.GripperOpen` in VB) you then have to wait for the move to finish (using `Robot.GripperFinish` in VB).

Similarly it looks like you need to wait for a `Robot.MoveStraight` to complete with a `Robot.Finish` etc.

Replace all of your sleep calls with the relevant wait commands and you will get rid of all of the unwanted [dead time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_time). Similarly if you wait for one move to finish before starting a subsequent move, you may prevent moves conflicting with eact other, confusing the control system.